# Link Excel to word document with VBA by selecting specific rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a word document from an Excel sheet.

For instance, in my excel table, I have different columns. One of them has the title of "colour". I can FILTER this column by the name of the different colours (eg "blue" , "green", "yellow" etc.).

Let's say I filter my column with the colour "blue".

What I would like to do in a VBA script, is to select all these rows that have the colour "blue" in commun and copy-paste them in a word document.

I thought I had it, but with the script I am using, I do not know why, but only the titles of my different columns is pasted, regardless what I define.

```
Sub TestOne()

Dim appWD As Word.Application, wbXL As Excel.Workbook

Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application.16")
appWD.Visible = True

debut = Range("A13").End(xlUp).Row
fin = Range("A15").End(xlUp).Row

For i = debut To fin
    'Copy the current row
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    'tell word to create new document.
    appWD.Documents.Add
    'Tell Word to paste the contents of the clipboard into the new document.
    appWD.Selection.Paste
Next i

'Close the new Word document.
appWD.ActiveDocument.Close

'Save the new document with a sequential file name.
appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="File"


' Close the new Word application.
appWD.Quit
Set appWD = Nothing

End Sub
```

If anyone has already done such a thing, or knows how to fix this script, I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: Your code doesn't select anything but it pastes the Selection. That *Selection* must be something selected before the code was started. Let me add that using the `Selection` object is bad practice. It's even worse when having more than one application because there can be a `Selection` only in the ActiveWindow of whichever application owns that window at any given moment while the code runs.

Comment: `Range("A13").End(xlUp)` means "Go to A13; from there move **Up** to find the first used cell; and return that cell as a Range". `Range("A13").End(xlUp).Row` would return the row number of that cell. More commonly, one would start looking from the last cell in a column, like `Cells(Rows.Count. "A")` to find the last used cell in column A, and start the loop at the first used cell, perhaps `Cells(2, "A")`. Not clear what you intend but your loop should be a very short one, perhaps only one cycle.